# Call function with setState from other component

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native

I have the following setup:

```
import {getNewImage} from '...'

export default class FirstClass extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            imageURL: 'www.test.com/new.jpg',
        }
    }

    update = () => {
         this.setState({
             imageURL: 'www.test.com/updated.jpg',
         })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Image
                    source={{ uri: this.state.imageURL }}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

```
import Class1 from '...'

export default class SecondClass extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => new FirstClass().update()}>
                <Class1></Class1>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        );
    }
}
```

The problem is: it doesn't update the imageURL. I tried multiple things. Logging this inside of update gave back the right object. But trying to log the `this.setState()` gives an **undefinded** back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose by `Class1` you mean `FirstClass`.

you should use the reference of the component using `ref`, not creating new instance of `FirstClass` class

checkout this code

```
export default class SecondClass extends Component {
    private firstClass = null;

    render() {
        return (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.firstClass.update()}>
                <Class1 ref={ref => this.firstClass = ref} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: You are my hero!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to update state in `Class1` similar to what do you want by [the react reference](https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit/issues/909#issuecomment-252969542).

But on my opinion this is non a good case and predictable behavior to change child component state from parent.

As another options you can add additional state to the `SecondClass` and pass it via props to child component. And inside `Class1` in [getDerivedStateFromProps](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops) based on that prop change state.

```js
export default class FirstClass extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      isNeedToUdpate: false,
      imageURL: "www.test.com/new.jpg"
    };
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    if (props.isNeedToUdpate !== state.isNeedToUdpate) {
      return {
        isNeedToUdpate: props.isNeedToUdpate,
        imageURL: "www.test.com/updated.jpg"
      };
    }

    return null;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Image source={{ uri: this.state.imageURL }} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

```js
export default class SecondClass extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      isNeedToUpdateClass1: false
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => {
          this.setState({ isNeedToUpdateClass1: true });
        }}
      >
        <Class1 isNeedToUpdate={this.state.isNeedToUpdateClass1}></Class1>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}
```